# PHP regular expression to replace values in a config file

Tags: php, regex

I need to use php to find and replace the database in a config file:

```
$cfg['database'] = 'my_database_name';
```

Basically, I'm trying to figure out a regular expression that would find everything between

```
 $cfg['database'] =
```

and

```
;
```

then replace it with the actual database name.  I think I would need to use preg_replace and then use the matches array, but I'm having a hard time trying to make it work.

Can someone give me an idea of how to go about this, or  point me to  a good resource that would address this specific type of replacement situation?

Comment: if you know definitively the line's contents, why do you need regex? Just use `if (strpos($line, '$cfg[\'database\'] = ') === 0) { $val = substr($line, 18, -1); }`. No need to regex it when you know the actual text to search for.

Comment: Thanks Brad, I hadn't thought of doing that way.  I tried it, and it worked fine.

Comment: Just for the hell of it: 
`preg_replace("/(.*'database'.*').*('.*)/" , "$1$newDatabasename$2" , $fileContent);`

Comment: Thanks @derp I changed yours to:  `preg_replace('/(^\$cfg\["database"\].*").*(".*)/'  , "$1$new_name$2" , $line);`  This was to find `$cfg["database"] = "my_database_name";`  Now I'm trying to figure out how to find either single quotes or double quotes around database.

Comment: You can do `[\'|"]`, this means either one. You see `'` has to be escaped in this case as you're using it to hold the regexp.

Comment: Seems you got it, if not the whole regexp should look like: `preg_replace('/(\$cfg\[[\'|"]database[\'|"]\].*[\'|"]).*([\'|"].*)/' , "$1$newDatabaseName$2" , $fileContent);` lol what a mess

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace('/(\$cfg\[\s*\'database\'\s*]\s*=\s*\').*(\'\s*;)', '$1' . $dbName . '$2', $text);
```